# How can I delete all fields after core(collection) was deleted

Tags: docker, solr, solrcloud

I am trying to delete core and all fields from index using

`http://localhost:port/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=<corename>&deleteInstanceDir=true`

but when I create index with same name using

`http://localhost:port/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=<corename>&configSet=_default`

all fields that was in deleted core with same name are already exists in index!

I am using Solr ver. 7.3 also I am using Docker and this package https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr

How can I delete core and all fields and all data permanently?

Comment: Are you sure that the configset hasn't been mutated? What is physically present on the disk after unloading the core? How long between deleting and creating the core?

Comment: @MatsLindh You are right, management-schema in _default config is modifying and don't change even if core is unloaded. But how can maybe can I clean _default config? Or maybe create some copy of it so I can delete it using API. I am runing solr in Docker so it is a little bit difficult to get access for it.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr#creating-cores maybe this will help

Comment: https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/issues/172 I have asked creator(or some of team members) of docker-solr about this. Maybe he will help.

Comment: You should post also how the docker image is started and how you've mounted the volume where solr cores stay, in short what's the environment where the docker-solr instance runs

Comment: Hi, I have received answer that solves part of problem https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/issues/172 , so at least I can try to create core with separate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

All docker images for Solr are third-party.  We on the Solr project know very little about them, and because of this, will have a very difficult time trying to support them.  The project has NOT created a docker image.  The one time that I looked at what somebody using a docker image had, it looked like the creator of the docker image had not installed Solr in the way that we would recommend.  They had created their own scripts for starting Solr instead of using what the project provided, and arranged the filesystem in a way very different than expected.

Is this SolrCloud, or standalone mode?  The fact that you're using the CoreAdmin API suggests that it's standalone -- when running in cloud mode, the CoreAdmin API should not be used -- it's an expert option.

When using the configset feature in standalone mode (which replicates the shared config paradigm found in SolrCloud, but only within a single server), anything you do that modifies the config will modify it for all cores on that machine that use the same configset, and for any cores you might create in the future using that configset.  This is not a bug, it's exactly what the configset feature is designed to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But do you plan to create your own docker image?

Comment: There are no plans at this time in the project to create an official docker image.  I do not know if that will change in the future.

Comment: Thanks @elyograg for info.